# ImportError, no module named

Tags: python

I get `ImportError: no module named Flopy` when I try to run the following script from an Anaconda prompt in the folder that the script it stored in, but when I run the script through Spyder it imports Flopy just fine and the rest of the code (not shown) which uses Flopy also works.

```
# import the required libraries
try:
    import flopy
except:
    fpth = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..'))
    sys.path.append(fpth)
    import flopy
```

The Spyder ran version never runs the code under than 'except' section since it managed to import Flopy at first try. I tried checking the path created by `os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..'))` and even copied the Flopy directory to that location and running the script from the Anaconda prompt started in that folder...which did make some difference, but the import failed with error: `ImportError: cannot import name getfullargspec`.

Any ideas why imports work one way but not the other?

Comment: *Install* (don't just copy a directory) `Flopy` on the Anaconda prompt.

Comment: Copying a package directory will ignore the relevant dependencies of that package; it also likely messes up your packaging system, to keep track of what's installed and what not.

Comment: It's already installed. `pip list` lists Flopy as an installed package. When running the script through the Spyder IDE it imports Flopy just fine, but it's only when running the exact same script by calling it from the command prompt that it fails to find the Flopy package.

Comment: How do you run your script from the command prompt?

Comment: I open an Anaconda prompt in the same folder (I added it with this method: https://gist.github.com/jiewpeng/8ba446acf329b1801bf91db767d179ea). It says that is is using the (base) environment (which is the one that has Flopy installed) and the path that is shows is correct. I then run the script by calling it by name (script.py).

Comment: Try `python -m pip install --ignore-installed Flopy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with help from @Jainal Patel! I just had to tidy up all my environment paths. There was an installed version of Python in C:\Python3, but Spyder was using the one in C:ProgramData\Anaconda.

Now when I open the command prompt, or an Anaconda prompt, or use Spyder, it uses the same Python environment and recognizes all my installed packages.

Answer (score -1):

```
!pip install flopy
try:
    import flopy
except:
    fpth = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..'))
    sys.path.append(fpth)
    import flopy
```

you need to install it first either using pip or conda

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but Flopy is alread installed. The script ran through Spyder finds the Flopy packages and imports them just fine, it's only when calling the script via the command prompt that it fails. Running `pip list` shows that Flopy is there.

Comment: Then check your system variables, there might be some other version of python in that command prompt system environments. check the versions running of the python and check the path of the python.   I think it simply means your command prompt is getting some other python environment than spyder.

Comment: Thanks @Jainil Patel, that seems to be the answer. When I open the command prompt and type pip list I get a slightly different list of installed packages than if I open the Anaconda prompt and do the same. How do I fix it so that the command prompt uses the same Python environment as Anaconda?

Comment: Fixed it! I just had to tidy up all my environment paths. There was an installed version of Python in C:\Python39, whereas Spyder was using the one in C:ProgramData\Anaconda.